# When is a timer released from memory

Tags: javascript, timer

Are timers set with `window.setTimeout` released from memory as soon as the callback function has executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are released when the garbage collection runs once there are no more references to the callback function. So it will not be cleared before the timeout expires, but it won't happen immediately after either.

This is not something you should have to worry about when using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Timers will be garbage collected after being cleared. This happens automatically when `setTimeout` times out, but notice that `setInterval` will not normally be garbage collected until `clearInterval` is explicitly called, which can potentially cause memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

The actual delay may be longer, which will be handeled by garbage collector.

for clearing you can use `window.clearTimeout()`

for more read : [MDN window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Not answering my question.

Comment: @VJD I'm afraid not. the question was about whether timers get cleared, not how to clear them.